# Display files from same folder name in different location

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory

How can I display files from same directory names but inside sub directories. Consider the folder structure as:

```
.
+ A
|   a.txt
|   b.txt
+ B
|   c.txt
|   d.txt
+ C
++   A
|      e.txt
++   B
+++      M
+++      B
|        g.txt
|   f.txt
```

Now if I specify directory as `B`, it must return `c.txt` , `d.txt` `f.txt` and `g.txt`.

I tried:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/user/main"):
    for dirs in root:
        if dirs == root:
            print files
```

But it is not returning anything. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print out root, dirs and files for each iteration, it will help figure what happens.

**"B" == root.split("\")[-1]** means the current os.walk is processing "D:/user/mian/xx/xx/B"

**len(files)** means just print out the files if exist, not print if non-exist.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/user/main"):
    if "B" == root.split("\\")[-1] and len(files) > 0:
        print (files)
```

Comment: ~ Thanks a lot :) gives exactly what I wanted.